# Is it wrong to use absolute value brackets instead of brackets if the value inside it is always positive?

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

We know that $∫{1\over x} dx$ $=$ $ln \lvert x\rvert$ $+$ $c$

If the $x$ within the natural logarithm is always positive, for example $x$ $=$ $3x^2$ $+$ $5$, should $∫{x\over 3x^2+5} dx$ be expressed as

$\int{x\over 3x^2+5} dx  ={1\over6}\ln \lvert 3x^2+5\rvert+ c$

**OR**

$\int{x\over 3x^2+5} dx={1\over6}\ln (3x^2+5)$ $+$ $c$

Would it be **wrong** to use absolute value brackets instead of brackets if the value inside is always positive? Is it necessary to take into account the possibility of $x$ being a complex number / an imaginary number and thus making $\ln (3x^2+5)$ negative?

Which expression is more accurate?

Comment: Logs do not work trivially with complex numbers, especially when it comes to integrals (and even more so for changes of variable). I would assume real-valued $x$ in which case you can feel free to keep or remove the absolute value bars. The formula with absolute values is a real-valued phenomenon anyway. (There is an extension for complex numbers.)

Comment: Nothing that is true is "wrong".  It may be obfuscating, redundant, inefficient, confusing and unnecessary.  But it isn't wrong.

Comment: Check this out for similar discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154321/lnz-as-antiderivative-of-1-z

Comment: And this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154428/antiderivative-1-z-on-mathbb-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the convention for a logarithm as the answer to an indefinite integral is $\ln |z|+C$, but if $|z|$ is positive, $\ln (z) + C$ is appropriate.  In general for indefinite integrals, if it assumed that any variable will be positive, the absolute value bars are not required and can be dropped - but for logarithms, I would still use parentheses if the expression is part of the logarithm.

In your case, either $$\int \dfrac {x \ dx}{3x^2 +5} = \frac {1}{6} \ln |3x^2 + 5|+C$$ or $$\int \dfrac {x \ dx}{3x^2 +5} = \frac {1}{6} \ln (3x^2 + 5)+C$$ is perfectly fine as an answer as $3x^2 + 5$ is positive for all $x$.

It's when you come to definite integrals where the absolute value bars may be necessary.  If $x \leq 0$, $\ln x$ is undefined in the reals; but if we get a value inside the absolute value bars that evaluates to a positive real number, the absolute value bars are not needed.